# How Initialize Vector2 Array in Java/libGdx without crashing

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I was using libGdx(may not relevant to the question I asked) to draw a truncated corner rectangle spiral, which for learning and fun.
But then I faced a question of trying to initialize a Vector2 Array with a set of Vector2 inside a loop to manipulate the set of coordinates,so that to reduce hard code it needed. How sad it is, as long as I run the program, it crashed. Such as

```
Vector2[] vectors = new Vector2[]{
    new Vector2(x1,y1),
    new Vector2(x2,y2),
    ...
};
```

and

```
Array<Vector2> coordinates = new Array<Vector2>();
coordinates.add(new vec1(x1,y1));
corrdinates.add(new vec2(x2,y2));
...
```

However,as I hard coded the set of vecotr2, the program run fluently.I believe that every time I initialized such a array, a array is cached (a kitten will die), so it is easily crashed.

Can somebody explain how to initialize an inline array inside a loop without crashes, or/and explain why it is easily crashes?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: when it run, it crashed, may be i created too much points at each loop? about a 100 points each time, loop about 100 times.

Comment: How does it crash? What is the error message?

Comment: Oh, I see ,i get run time over because i initialize a infinite loop. Thank you ,you help me solved.

Comment: Can I asked that, how to save memory from initialize array each time.